# Right side drawer - text and icon alignment

Tags: mobile, mobile-application, alignment, drawer

I want to give my users option to chose between right and left drawer and I'm wondering how to align elements in a Left-To-Right language. Bellow there are few examples but I want to hear your opinion on the alignment.

Additionally, should I also offer alignment option? For example, if a left-handed person chooses a left drawer, their thumb would obscure the icon and maybe text, and they would have to move the thumb to reveal the option. But if a right-handed person chooses a left drawer, the alignment is ok. So, I could offer right drawer with left and right alignment and a left drawer with left and right alignment. Or am I overthinking this?

[image: design 1]
[image: design 2]

For reference, this is how the *standard* left drawer looks

[image: standard design]

Answer (score 1):

I think you overcomplicating this and it won't make that big of a difference. Choose the location of the menu toggle, left or right (you can run an A/B test to find which one was preferred by your users) and then stay consistent with that choice.